# How can I have the same size both side using <hr>?

Tags: html, css

Here's my problem if I don't use a `<br>` after `<hr>` my image goes away like this:

[image]

So I added the `<br>`, and now I have this result:

[image]

I used some margin to reduce the size of the blank space, but I'd like to be close such as this result I designed:

[image]

Here's my HTML code:

```css
.articleactu {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-gap: 36px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 190px auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.articleactu img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 650px;
}

p1 {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #662189;
}

hr.solid {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 480%;
  opacity: 12%;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/vanguard.jpeg" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
<div>
  <p1>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p1>
  <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>

  <p2> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p2>
</div>
<hr class="solid">
<br>
<img src="images/marvel.jpg" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
<div>
  <p1>MARVEL AVENGERS : Le personnage de Spider-Man bientôt dans le jeu.</p1>
  <p> Les fans demandent, Square Enix donne. En effet, Spider-Man sera bientôt jouable dans le jeu sortit il y a peu via DLC...</p>
  <p2> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p2>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Use flexbox, you'll thank me later

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm so bad at using flexbox. I'm still learning but can't get it working this way so I guess I chose another difficult way

Comment: may be change hr.solid class to : { margin : 30px auto 20px auto;}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this one :  { margin : 10px auto -10px auto;}, that works but it's still a bit too far, not like the result I'd like to obtain..

Comment: if someone could help me at how I could reach my result using flexbox, I'm in ! That'd be awesome

Comment: That <br> after <hr class="solid"> creates a little problem for the set margin. so remove it.

Comment: I did. I still have the same issue. I posted the screenshot issue in my topic. Now the image is on top of the line, but still moved away on the right lol

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a flexbox sample of your code and need some change, good luck.

```css
 .flex-container {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    gap: 5px;

  }

  .flex-container > div{
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  }
.articleactu {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-gap: 36px;

}

.articleactu img {
    border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
   max-width: 650px;
}

p1 {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #662189;
}

hr.solid {
  margin : 10px auto 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   

<div>
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
  <p1>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p1>
  <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>

  <p2> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p2>
</div>
<hr class="solid">
<div>
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
  <p1>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p1>
  <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>

  <p2> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p2>
</div>
<hr class="solid">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is as follows, though bear in mind I've taken the liberty of replacing the non-standard HTML elements, `<p1>` and `<p2>`, replacing them with the valid `<p>` element:

```css
/* a simple reset, in order to ensure all elements have
   the same defaults: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #030;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  /* we're using CSS flex-box layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* we want the content to wrap, as the <img> and
     <div>, containing the text, are visually adjacent,
     but we want the content to appear in a vertical
     orientation: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* defining a visual separation between elements: */
  gap: 1em;
}

.wrapper img {
  /* defining the width of the <img> element: */
  width: 200px;
  /* along with setting that <img> to fully-cover
     its available dimension in the layout: */
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* defining styles for <img> elements that aren't
   successfully loaded */
.wrapper img:empty {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 10px, #ccc 10px 15px);
  text-align: center;
}


/* here we style the <div> elements that follow the <img>
   elements: */
.wrapper img + div {
  /* we set the <div> to allow it to grow to occupy space available: */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* we set the flex-basis to 50% in order that, when the element
     occupies 50% of the available space, the layout shifts to
     occupy two rows, with the <img> above the <div>: */
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

hr.solid {
  /* the <hr> is a flex-item, and here we use the flex
     shorthand to set the flex-grow, flex-shrink and
     flex-basis properties, to allow it to grow, not allow
     it to shrink and set its width as 100%: */
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}


/* assuming that you don't want a trailing <hr> element at the
   end of the list of articles; if you do this can be removed: */
hr:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- the following '.wrapper' element is added to contain the list of elements you're
     showing, though if no parent element exists the CSS could be applied to the <body>
     element instead: -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="images/vanguard.jpeg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
  <div>
    <p>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p>
    <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>
  <hr class="solid">

  <img src="images/marvel.jpg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
  <div>
    <p>MARVEL AVENGERS : Le personnage de Spider-Man bientôt dans le jeu.</p>
    <p> Les fans demandent, Square Enix donne. En effet, Spider-Man sera bientôt jouable dans le jeu sortit il y a peu via DLC...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>
  <hr class="solid">
</div>
```

This is easier to layout, though, if you wrap the `<img>` element inside the `<div>` with the text content and then use CSS grid to style that `<div>`:

```css
/* simple reset: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #030;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* because related elements - the <img> and the text - are
     all contained within the same descendant element, we can
     use flex-direction to force the content into a vertical
     orientation: */
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1em;
}

/* I applied a class-name to easily access and style the <div>
   elements that contain the content: */
div.card {
  /* here we use CSS grid layout, which allows for a two-
     dimensional layout of the contents: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining the vertical, and horizontal, gaps between
     adjacent tracks (columns/rows): */
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  /* defining the named grid areas, here we define three
     rows of content, each row with two named columns: */
  grid-template-areas:
    "img title"
    "img content"
    "img release-date";
  /* we then define the widths of those columns; the first
     named 'img' is 200px wide, and the second is as wide
     as possible to occupy the remaining space once the
     width of the 'img' column is removed: */
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
}

.wrapper img {
  /* we specified already that the 'img' area is 200px in
     width; here specify that the <img> should fill the
     available space (without distorting the aspect-ratio): */
  object-fit: cover;
  /* we place the <img> element in the 'img' area of the
     containing grid: */
  grid-area: img;
}

.wrapper img:empty {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 10px, #ccc 10px 15px);
  text-align: center;
}

hr.solid {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

hr.solid:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- applying a somewhat meaningful class-name to the <div> element(s) which
       contain the content: -->
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/vanguard.jpeg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <p>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p>
    <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>

  <hr class="solid">

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/marvel.jpg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <p>MARVEL AVENGERS : Le personnage de Spider-Man bientôt dans le jeu.</p>
    <p> Les fans demandent, Square Enix donne. En effet, Spider-Man sera bientôt jouable dans le jeu sortit il y a peu via DLC...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>

  <hr class="solid">
</div>
```

Of course, the above can be further simplified by removing the `<hr>` elements, and instead using CSS generated content to create the separators:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #030;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1em;
}

div.card {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img title"
    "img content"
    "img release-date"
    /* a grid-item will only occupy one track (row/column) by
       default, so here we add a two-column grid-area named 'hr'
       for the psuedo-<hr> to occupy: */
    "hr hr";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
}

/* we use the ::after pseudo-element to create the visual line: */
div.card::after {
  background-color: currentColor;
  /* for a pseudo-element to be rendered the content, even if
     only an empty string, must be set: */
  content: '';
  /* we place the element - rendered as a grid-item - into the
     'hr' grid-area: */
  grid-area: hr;
  height: 3px;
  /* we add a margin-top to adjust the spacing of the pseudo-
     element, so it's visually centred between the adjacent cards: */
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  grid-area: img;
}

.wrapper img:empty {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 10px, #ccc 10px 15px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/vanguard.jpeg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <p>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p>
    <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/marvel.jpg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <p>MARVEL AVENGERS : Le personnage de Spider-Man bientôt dans le jeu.</p>
    <p> Les fans demandent, Square Enix donne. En effet, Spider-Man sera bientôt jouable dans le jeu sortit il y a peu via DLC...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming that you don't want the trailing pseudo-element to create a line at the end of the content a further refinement can be used; here we use the `:not()` negation operator to refine the selector so that we select all `::after` pseudo-elements of all `div.card` elements that are *not* the `:last-child` of their parent:

```
div.card:not(:last-child)::after {
  background-color: currentColor;
  content: '';
  grid-area: hr;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #030;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1em;
}

div.card {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img title"
    "img content"
    "img release-date"
    "hr hr";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
}

div.card:not(:last-child)::after {
  background-color: currentColor;
  content: '';
  grid-area: hr;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  grid-area: img;
}

.wrapper img:empty {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 10px, #ccc 10px 15px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/vanguard.jpeg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <p>CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</p>
    <p> Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/marvel.jpg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <p>MARVEL AVENGERS : Le personnage de Spider-Man bientôt dans le jeu.</p>
    <p> Les fans demandent, Square Enix donne. En effet, Spider-Man sera bientôt jouable dans le jeu sortit il y a peu via DLC...</p>
    <p> Publié le 25 novembre 2021 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd also, in closing, recommend that you use more semantic means to wrap the text-content; it *looks* like you have content such as a title, article text and a release date? If so, I'd personally – and this *is* highly subjective – update the HTML to the following:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #030;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1em;
}

div.card {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img title"
    "img content"
    "img release-date"
    "hr hr";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
}

div.card:not(:last-child)::after {
  background-color: currentColor;
  content: '';
  grid-area: hr;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.card h2.title {
  color: #050;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* here we select all ::before pseudo-elements of
   all <time> elements that have a 'data-prefix'
   custom attribute: */
time[data-prefix]::before {
  /* setting the content to be equal to the value of
     the 'data-prefix' attribute, using the attr()
     function, and adding a string to follow that
     attribute-value: */
  content: attr(data-prefix) ': ';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  grid-area: img;
}

.wrapper img:empty {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 10px, #ccc 10px 15px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/vanguard.jpeg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <!-- a page should have a <h1> element to title the page or document; here I use a
         <h2> element (though any other type of heading element could be used) as it's
         hierarchically/semantically less important than the page-title; if the cards
         appear in a section that itself has a heading, this element should be titled
         with a lower-significance heading, <h3>, <h4>... -->
    <h2 class="title">CALL OF DUTY : VANGUARD : Est-il bon ?</h2>
    <p>Les avis des fans de la saga sont mitigés et ça peut se comprendre, plusieurs bugs ont été détectés et empêche les joueurs de jouer convenablement...</p>
    <!-- in order to make the date of release (arguably) accessible to user-agents that
         can parse such information I chose to use a <time> element with the datatime
         attribute set to the referenced date: -->
    <time class="release-date" datetime="2021-11-25" data-prefix="Publié le">25 novembre 2021 </time>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/marvel.jpg" alt="Article GTA" class="center">
    <h2 class="title">MARVEL AVENGERS : Le personnage de Spider-Man bientôt dans le jeu.</h2>
    <p> Les fans demandent, Square Enix donne. En effet, Spider-Man sera bientôt jouable dans le jeu sortit il y a peu via DLC...</p>
    <time class="release-date" datetime="2021-11-25" data-prefix="Publié le">25 novembre 2021 </time>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Adjacent-sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).
  - [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()).
  - [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`flex` (shorthand)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).
  - [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).
  - [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
  - `object-fit`.
  - [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
- HTML:

  - [`<time>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time).
  - [`<h2>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/h2).

Bibliography:

- "[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)."
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)."
- "[<h1>–<h6>: The HTML Section Heading Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)."

Answer (score 1):

You should always post **working** code. At the very least I assume you  forgot to add the `<div class="articleactu">`.

Also `p1` and `p2` are not valid HTML elements. If you want to style them differently, use a valid element (such as `p`) and classes.

Your problem is that you forgot that the `<hr>` elements also are included in the grid.

The elements inside the grid, are distributed (by default) from the top left, row by row. Without the `<br>` something like this:

```
+-------+-------+
|  img  |  div  |
+-------+-------+
|  hr   |  img  |
+-------+-------+
|  div  |       |
+-------+-------+
```

By adding the `<br>` you are adding an element that is then placed into the second column:

```
+-------+-------+
|  img  |  div  |
+-------+-------+
|  hr   |  br   |
+-------+-------+
|  img  |  div  |
+-------+-------+
```

However now the `<hr>` only covers the first column which you try to compensate with the `width`.

Instead you need to tell the hr, to cover two columns like this:

```
+-------+-------+
|  img  |  div  |
+-------+-------+
|      hr       |
+-------+-------+
|  img  |  div  |
+-------+-------+
```

This can be done, for example with the `grid-columns` property and the `span` keyword:

```
hr.solid {
  grid-column: span 2;
  with: 100%
  opacity: 12%;
}
```

The width is needed, because as a grid element the `<hr>` looses it default width. Also remove the negative margin.

The large gap around the `<hr>` is due to `grid-gap: 36px` with applies to vertical and horizontal gaps. To reduce the distance around the `<hr>`, set a separate value for the horizontal gaps:

```
grid-gap: 0 36px;
```

For a complete example look at https://jsfiddle.net/3qywz8e7/1/

BTW, you should learn to use the developer tools of your browser. They have tools built in to help you visualize the grid. For example in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/grid/